# How to express logarithms verbally?

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics

I'm preparing for the job interview. One of the topics I'm studing is algorithms analysis, which uses so called [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). So, the problem is, I actually don't know how to properly pronounce those designations, for example, `O(n log n)`. A few more examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions).

The most interesting case is `O(n log n)`, because here we have a function `O`, multiplication `n * log n` and logarithm `log n` together.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say _oh en log en_ but then again I might be laughed at if I do so. I _do_ know multiplication doesn't have to be pronounced, think of "ee equals em cee squared".

Comment: https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/premba/analytical/s4/s4_2.cfm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*O(n log n)* is typically pronounced "Oh of en log n". The English for big O notation is written out fully as "on the order of...", but when having a technical discussion, abbreviations are perfectly acceptable. However, it's typical to keep *of* in place to separate the function's identifier from its content. For example, *f(3x^2)* would be said as "F of three X squared". If you're strictly having a discussion about big O notation, you might omit the *of*, since the context eliminates the possible ambiguity.

Comment: I would include the word "big" to avoid ambiguity between small-oh and big-oh. I would typically pronounce it without the *of* as well: "big oh en log en"

Answer (score 7):

The other answer does a good job of covering the pronunciation of the actual notation, but I would like to add that in some cases you can just call it **linearithmic time**.

A few useful time complexities and their names:

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ Complexity   ║ Name            ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ O(1)         ║ constant        ║
║ O(log n)     ║ logarithmic     ║
║ O((log n)^k) ║ polylogarithmic ║
║ O(n)         ║ linear          ║
║ O(n log n)   ║ linearithmic    ║
║ O(n^k)       ║ polynomial      ║
║ O(2^(n^k))   ║ exponential     ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

(You can find a [more complete list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity))

Comment: I would say that these are more widely used than actually pronouncing things like *Oh of en log en*. They take less cognition to recognize the actual *meaning* behind them. Now if you were asked to 'compute' the *exact* time complexity, e.g. `O(4n^2)`, and then *simplify*, one would pronounce the full notation *Oh of four en squared*, and then simplify to *the algorithm runs in polynomial time*.